# OPTIONS 405 (Method Not Allowed) and Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api..' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, angular5, ionic4

I try to upload image using api capture with camera and then convert image in base64 and try to upload but it gives error.

```
public abc:string;
```

```
 this.abc="/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUTExMWFhUXGB8aGRYYGSEgIRo.............
```

```
sendPostRequest() {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');        
        let postData ={
            "AudometerCapture":this.abc,                          
            "Door1":this.abc,
            "Door2":this.abc,
          "Door3":this.abc,
            "Door4":this.abc,
          "TransactionID": 27
        }

         this.httpClient.post('http://apiearningwheels.sharpnettechnology.com/api/DailyImageUpload/UploadDailyImages',JSON.stringify(postData),{headers:headers})
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(data=>{
            this.showLongToast("Result is :- " + data);
            console.log('result',data);
          }, error => {
            console.log('error',error);
            this.showLongToast("Error is  :- " + error);
          });
  }
```

when execute the api in postman work successfully.like this pass data as raw value then its work correctly.
[image: pass data as raw value then its work correctly]

Answer (score 0):

for the CORS policy , the headers from the XMLHttpRequest which  you are accessing to that API are in proper.
Once check the Headers in postman and your code.
And also try once without using the headers.
refer here : [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: i pass the header "content type : application/json" which is pass in postman but still not working.

Comment: when i remove the header it give the 415 Unsupported Media Type error

Comment: Door1 , Door2,.... are the values consists of same base 64 values, here the max size of the json request is exceeding.

Comment: pass only AudometerCapture  value in to that api and try

Comment: Try to consume the api on server side , where you can check the API request and response flow.